# How do I get my flexbox to expand vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, transition

I was given code that uses a flexbox layout module. The box-orient property is set to horizontal and I am being asked to modify the code to set it to use a vertical flexbox and to expand vertically when hovering over the box.

I've changed the -webkit-box-orient to vertical and the box-orient to vertical.(original code it was horizontal) I also changed the margin to 0px (original code had margin as 10 px -10px 10px 0 px) I am told not to have any space between boxes which is why I changed the margin. Everything is original code. 
I tried changing the transition and using transform but I still need the ease-out transition and changing that part of the code makes the ease-out go away.

```
.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

.flexbox>div {
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px dimgrey;
}
```

I just need help figuring out how to get the boxes to expand vertically instead of horizontally when hovered over. The entire code is not listed above, just a snippet.

Comment: please share you HTML

Comment: http://prism.troy.edu/ddixon161526/week2/exercise5.13.html

Comment: Is `display:flex;` optionnal or are you running old browsers only ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this by animating the `p` with `max-width`

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 90px;
  height: 420px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

.flexbox>div {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px dimgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:hover {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexbox>div:hover p {
  max-height: 1000px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

p {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Rosario";
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<div class="flexbox">
  <div><img src="GPP.png" alt="Good programming practice icon">
    <p>Good Programming Practices call attention to techniques that will help you produce programs that are clearer, more understandable and more maintainable.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="EPT.png" alt="Error prevention tip icon">
    <p>Error-Prevention Tips contain suggestions for exposing bugs and removing them from your programs; many describe aspects of programming that prevent bugs from getting into programs in the first place.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="CPE.png" alt="Common programming error icon">
    <p>Common Programming Errors point out the errors that students tend to make frequently. These Common Programming Errors reduce the likelihood that you'll make the same mistakes.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="SEO.png">
    <p>Software Engineering Observations highlight architectural and design issues that affect the construction of software systemms, especially large-scale systems.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't think of using an animation.